# Chrome instance not opening due to watchdog timeout issue in Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am getting the below error from today when I run my test suite. I am using chrome driver since our Application runs only on chrome. The same scripts are running fine in another machine.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7) on port 37280
Only local connections are allowed.
Nov 12, 2014 11:33:36 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2).org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@1c06d198
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'MyTerminal', ip: '10.54.205.137', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',  os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:181)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:128)
   at ChromeTest.main(ChromeTest.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'MyTerminal', ip: '10.54.205.137', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
   ... 7 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:37280/status] to be available after 20001 ms
   at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
   ... 9 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
   at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
   ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
   ... 11 more
```

I have used following trouble shooting steps. 
1. Tried disabling the `gpu-watchdog` in chrome
2. Re-Installed Chrome
3. Re-cloned all my project from git hub
4. Installed older version.

I don't have luck to run this. Can some one point me in right direction If I am missing something here.

My concern is these scripts ran till yesterday and suddenly I am getting this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running out all possible options, At last I found a little solution for this. I played a trick with the chrome driver versions, But not sure why and how it worked. I have followed these steps

1. I have downloaded the latest version of chrome driver and ran my
   selenium tests by configuring `System.setProperty()`
2. Now I double clicked the old chrome driver version (which I have used it for my
   script earlier) while running my selenium script.
3. Then I configured my script back to my old version.

That's it my scripts are running smooth without any exceptions. :-)